# 'method' object is not iterable when iterating over a list

Tags: python, class

I am writing a program to score a card game I like to play and have the following class `Game()` with the following method:

```
def score(self):
    scores = []
    for name in self.players:
      score = name.score_round()
      scores.append(score)
    scores = pd.concat(scores)
    scores = scores.groupby('Player').Score.sum()
    return scores
```

`self.players` is a list made during the `__init__` method of the all the players in the game, each having their own `Player()` class. When I call this method though, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 game.score()

~/dev/code_education/backalley/scoring.py in score(self)
     91   def score(self):
     92     scores = []
---> 93     for name in self.players:
     94       score = name.score_round()
     95       scores.append(score)

TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

I thought that I'd be iterating over a list, but I'm clearly missing something. Are class variables such as self.players also considered methods?

Comment: can you include your __init__ method?

Comment: def __init__(self, names):
    self.players = names
    self.names = [print(i) for i in names]
    self.max_hand = (54 - len(names) % 54) / len(names)
    self.round_number = 1
    self.count = 1
    self.ascending = True

Comment: names is the list of `Player()` classes

Comment: maybe you pass Player objects into list as a method

Answer (score 1):

`self.players` returns the method object, it doesn't call it. You should follow it with `()` to make it a method call:

```
for name in self.players():
    # Here -------------^
```

Comment: right, the object is what I want, I'm trying to get that list.

Answer (score 0):

> Are class variables such as self.players also considered methods?

No, but you're using the method name `score()` and then trying to append it to the list. This is where your problem lies.

Comment: So since my method variable is the same name as the method it's getting messed up?

Comment: Either that or the answer from @Mureinik, yes.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. Where do you see a method named `score()`, and what does that have to do with `for name in self.players:` failing?

Comment: `def score()` <=== method named score -- it's an additional problem that will crop up once this one is sorted.

Comment: The `score` they're trying to append isn't the method but the value computed in the line before. And even without that, the method wouldn't be accessible as `score` because it would need `self.`. So not only does this "answer" not address the question, but addresses something that's not even true in any way.

Comment: TIL, but you could have been a little less spergy about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the say I had the `__repr__` setup. Thanks for your help though!